# I'm having trouble with my query. Once I add an addition where before the group by, it says that I have a group by error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The sample data:

```
+ -----+------+--------+------+------+---------+------------+--------+
| clid | cust | symbol | side | oQty | fillQty | fillPx     | execid |
+ -----+------+--------+------+------+---------+------------+--------+
| 274  | C2   | INTC   | SELL | 2000 | 167     | 12.09      | 1      |
| 188  | C9   | SBS    | SELL | 2000 | 121     | 38.599998  | 2      |
| 155  | C1   | C      | SELL | 1500 | 159     | 50.650002  | 3      |
| 294  | C5   | BMY    | BUY  | 2000 | 667     | 13.648224  | 4      |
| 276  | C7   | FCX    | BUY  | 2000 | 91      | 26.59      | 5      |
| 255  | C9   | FCX    | SELL | 2000 | 231     | 26.389999  | 6      |
| 276  | C7   | FCX    | BUY  | 2000 | 182     | 30         | 7      |
| 277  | C1   | BMY    | BUY  | 2000 | 1333    | 11.61      | 8      |
| 188  | C9   | SBS    | SELL | 2000 | 91      | 40.860001  | 9      |
| 133  | C5   | BMY    | SELL | 5000 | 636     | 12.721739  | 10     |
| 110  | C7   | AA     | BUY  | 5000 | 182     | 8.359823   | 11     |
| 120  | C7   | IBM    | BUY  | 5000 | 111     | 72.419998  | 12     |
| 152  | C2   | BA     | BUY  | 1500 | 167     | 142.690002 | 13     |
| 276  | C7   | FCX    | BUY  | 2000 | 273     | 28.25      | 14     |
+ -----+------+--------+------+------+---------+------------+--------+
```

```
cust    side    symbol  qty clid
C5  SELL    F   2000    257
C6  BUY AMZN    1500    203
C7  BUY IBM 5000    120
C6  BUY F   5000    228
C1  BUY UNH 5000    172
C1  SELL    FCX 2000    242
C8  BUY F   2000    186
C5  BUY BMY 2000    294
C1  SELL    SBS 2000    212
C9  SELL    SBS 2000    194
C6  SELL    FB  1500    232
C3  SELL    AMZN    2000    113
C9  BUY BAC 5000    102
C8  BUY BMY 5000    227
C9  SELL    FB  5000    296
C2  SELL    INTC    2000    274
C6  SELL    C   2000    171
```

A customer will submit a buy order to buy X shares and the oqty is the partial order that processed. What I want to do is find the number of fulfilled orders and the average price of the order.

This works:

```
select clid, oQty, sum(fillqty) 
from 
(select clid, side, oQty, fillqty, fillpx, execid 
from fills where side='buy' group by clid, fillqty) A 
group by clid;
```

This doesn't work:

```
select clid, oQty, sum(fillqty) 
from 
(select clid, side, oQty, fillqty, fillpx, execid from fills where side='buy' group by clid, fillqty) A 
where oQty = sum(fillqty) 
group by clid;
```

> ERROR 1111 (HY000):  Invalid use of group function

I don't understand why I can't add a comparison right before the group by... Can someone explain why there's an error?

Comment: Please add sample data for your table and the expected output.

Comment: You should read up on sql order of operations. In this case the where is executed before the group by so the where clause doesn't know about the sum(fillqty).

Comment: you need one group by, because if one sql is already groupby child then what else you will get by doing groupby again

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: You obviously don't know yet what `GROUP BY` does. In your subquery you say you want to group by clid and fillqty. This is supposed to aggregate your rows, so you get one row per clid/fillqty. Is it even possible to find more than one record per clid/fillqty? Your example doesn't contain such rows. If it's not possible (because clid/fillqty is unique in your table), then why group by them? And if it's possible, then which side, oQty, fillpx, and execid do you expect to retrieve for a clid/fillqty? There can be various values to pick from.

Comment: As to your request: You should tell us what the unique or primary key of the table is. You should also tell us what `clid` and `fillqty` are. They seem to play a vital role in your query, but you haven't even mentioned what they represent.

Comment: Is `fills` a view? If it is a table, this looks very much like a bad database design, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: There is another table but I wasn't sure if it was relevant

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use aggregate functions, like `SUM` in your case, in `WHERE` clause. Use `HAVING`.

Create an alias in `SELECT` statement and use it in `HAVING` clause. This is more optimized way as it avoids calculating the sum again.

```
select clid, oQty, sum(fillqty) AS SumQty
from 
(select clid, side, oQty, fillqty, fillpx, execid 
from fills where side='buy' group by clid, fillqty) A 
group by clid
having SumQty = oQty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it should

```
    Select * 
    From
    (select clid, oQty, sum(fillqty) as SUM 
    from 
    (select clid, side, oQty, fillqty, fillpx, execid 
    from fills where side='buy' group by clid, fillqty) A 
    group by clid)B
    where B.SUM=B.oQty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing aggregate function in comparison ,thus, you must use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
select clid, oQty, sum(fillqty) 
from 
(select clid, side, oQty, fillqty, fillpx, execid from fills where side='buy' group by clid, fillqty) A 
having  sum(fillqty) = oQty 
group by clid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that clid,cust,side and oqty are the same for each partial fill you can do without the sub query and simply use max or min to get the the distinct oqty using a group by and a having clause to test for example

```
 select clid,group_concat(side),group_concat(oqty),min(oqty),max(oqty) maxoqty,sum(fillqty) sumfill,count(*), 
                sum(fillpx),avg(fillpx)
from fills
where side = 'buy'
group by clid having maxoqty <> sumfill;
```

Note I have thrown in some other aggregations for the fun of it.

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| clid | group_concat(side) | group_concat(oqty) | min(oqty) | maxoqty | sumfill | count(*) | sum(fillpx) | avg(fillpx) |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  110 | BUY                | 5000               |      5000 |    5000 |     182 |        1 |        8.36 |    8.360000 |
|  120 | BUY                | 5000               |      5000 |    5000 |     111 |        1 |       72.42 |   72.420000 |
|  152 | BUY                | 1500               |      1500 |    1500 |     167 |        1 |      142.69 |  142.690000 |
|  276 | BUY,BUY,BUY        | 2000,2000,2000     |      2000 |    2000 |     546 |        3 |       84.84 |   28.280000 |
|  277 | BUY                | 2000               |      2000 |    2000 |    1333 |        1 |       11.61 |   11.610000 |
|  294 | BUY                | 2000               |      2000 |    2000 |     667 |        1 |       13.65 |   13.650000 |
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```